# Mvn install fails every time

Tags: java, maven

I've just finished intergration of my web-projects with AspectJ  and come across with the following issue:

I have two projects: `api` (containning aspects), `web-app`, where `web-app` depends on `api`. I'm using Java 7 and declare the following plugins in the `api` projects:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.7</version>
   <configuration>
      <outxml>true</outxml>
      <XterminateAfterCompilation>true</XterminateAfterCompilation>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>compile</id>
           <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The web-app project contains the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <outxml>true</outxml>
        <XterminateAfterCompilation>true</XterminateAfterCompilation>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>ua.com.winforce</groupId>
                <artifactId>casino_aspect</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
     </configuration>

     <executions>
         <execution>
             <goals>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
</plugin>
```

And the issue is when I try to run `mvn instal` rigth after performing `mvn clean` it fails with multiple errors like that:

```
 Syntax error, annotations are only available 
 if source level is 1.5 or greater
```

But the second `mvn install` works just fine. Is that a bug of AspectJ plugin?

Comment: Set java version to aspect plugin.

Comment: @AleksandrM Should I do that in both web-app and api projects?

Comment: right click on project > Properties > Project Facets > Java  (Set java Version to 7)

Comment: @ravi What about pom.xml way? I need to allow continious integration server performs it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the source level to your `aspectj maven plugin`:

`<configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
</configuration>`

Comment: what porject should I place this configuration in?

Comment: every project that needs to compile aspects with jdk 1.7

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.7:compile (compile) on project __Project_name__: AJC compiler errors:
 Got the following error now: `error Missing message: configure.incompatibleComplianceForSource in: org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.messages
 error no sources specified`
` abort AspectJ Compiler 1.8.2`.

Comment: Ah, I just need to `<complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>`, now it works fine. Thank you. I'll accept the answer as a correct.

Comment: BTW, you might edit the code in the answer.

Comment: Done, thanks @user3663882!